# JQuery Validation of Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I am having a lot of trouble trying to modify the errorClass and validClass with Jquery validation.

I assume all I need to do is add the .validate function and set the parameters.

Whilst the validation does fire and the validation message is shown, the classes are still changed to the standard "input-validation-error" or "valid".

There are no JQuery errors thrown in the browser.

I believe the problem may be something to do with the unobtrusive plugin preventing the jquery.validate settings being applied.

> JQuery  v3.7.0, Jquery-validate v1.19.5, Jquery-validate-unobtrusive
> v4.0.0

Script:

```
@section Scripts {
  $(document).ready(function (e) {
            $("#myForm").validate({
                errorClass: "is-invalid",
                validClass: "is-valid"
            });
  });
}
```

Razor Page:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label asp-for="ADR.AircraftID" class="form-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="ADR.AircraftID" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Aircraft,"AircraftID","Registration"))" class="form-select" required>
                <option></option>
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="ADR.AircraftID" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label asp-for="ADR.PersonID" class="form-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="ADR.PersonID" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Person,"PersonID","FullName"))" class="form-select" required>
                <option></option>
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="ADR.PersonID" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label asp-for="ADR.Date" class="form-label"></label>
            <kendo-datepicker for="ADR.Date" class="form-control" required></kendo-datepicker>
            <span asp-validation-for="ADR.Date" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label asp-for="ADR.TTIS" class="form-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="ADR.TTIS" class="form-control" required />
            <span asp-validation-for="ADR.TTIS" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <label asp-for="ADR.Details" class="form-label"></label>
            <textarea asp-for="ADR.Details" class="form-control" rows="3" required></textarea>
            <span asp-validation-for="ADR.Details" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="form-check">
        <input asp-for="ADR.Deferred" class="form-check-input isdeferred" type="checkbox" />
        <label asp-for="ADR.Deferred" class="form-check-label"></label>
        <span asp-validation-for="ADR.Deferred" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label asp-for="ADR.MELRef" class="form-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="ADR.MELRef" class="form-control deferred" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ADR.MELRef" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <label asp-for="ADR.DeferralExpiry" class="form-label"></label>
            <kendo-datepicker for="ADR.DeferralExpiry" class="form-control deferred"></kendo-datepicker>
            <span asp-validation-for="ADR.DeferralExpiry" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end">
        <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary" asp-page="./Index"> Close</a>
        <input type="submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Header:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - FlightLog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" /> 
  
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>    
   
    <link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.2.621/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.2.621/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.2.621/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.2.621/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.2.510/js/cultures/kendo.culture.en-NZ.min.js"></script>       
</head>
```

Comment: *"I believe the problem may be something to do with the unobtrusive plugin preventing the jquery.validate settings being applied."* - Exactly.  When using Unobtrusive, the `.validate()` parameters are constructed and applied automatically.  When you construct your own, they will be ignored.  The plugin only pays attention to the first instance of `.validate()` and ignores the rest.  A crude workaround might be to use `.setDefaults()` because this is another way to define parameters but the timing is critical.

Comment: @Sparky, thanks - that set me on the write path, weirdly using .setDefaults(), the validClass does work but the errorClass is either ignored or overwritten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the highlight and unhighlight functions within .setDefaults causes the validation to fire before the submit button is used.

The solution for myself was instead to set the custom classes in both the validator and unobtrusive settings.

```
const validationCustomSettings = {
    validClass: "is-valid",
    errorClass: "is-invalid",
};
       
jQuery.validator.setDefaults(validationCustomSettings);           
jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.options = validationCustomSettings;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try as below:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
 <script>
$.validator.setDefaults({
    validClass: "is-valid",
    // set error class doesn't work here ,so i have to try with hard code for error class
    //errorClass: "is-invalid",
          
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).addClass("is-invalid").removeClass(validClass);
        
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).addClass(validClass).removeClass("is-invalid");
    },
});
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: +1 Thanks, nice answer, but I was trying to avoid the highlight and unlight methods as this means the validation will fire as soon as the users cursor leaves the input box.  I would prefer the validation to only first fire on clicking submit.  After that it can fire on highlight/unhighlight.